# Using python itertools for nested for loops with in between actions

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-loops, python-itertools

I would like to convert the following nested for loop to use itertools.

```
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        for k in range(K):
            do_sth()
            for ii in range(II):
                for jj in range(JJ):
                    do_sth_else()
                do_third_thing()
```

I have written sth but I am wondering if it there is a more pythonic way of doing it.

```
for i, j, k in itertools.product(range(I), range(J), range(K)):
    do_sth()
    for ii in range(II):
        for jj in range(JJ):
            do_sth_else()
        do_third_thing()
```

Comment: why dont you replace `for ii in range(II): for jj in range(JJ)` with `itertools.product(range(II), range(JJ)` just as you did with the outer loops.

Comment: Because there is another function after the second (jj) for loop. I am just trying to get a feel on what is the best way to write this.